# React Hooks and React lifecycle Methods

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

I am new to reactjs and react native. when started learning the basics, I found various information about the react hooks and react life cycle methods. I know there were 7 lifecycle methods before react 16.3 but now there are just 6 of them. Can anyone elaborate this lifecycle methods and react hooks with some examples. this might help me to learn faster.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) I'm afraid this question is **far** too broad and open-ended for SO's Q&A format. Your best bet is the React website, tutorials, books, ...

Comment: I think that's not a good way to ask a question elaborating all the hooks here will be so confusing. It's better you study first then ask if you face any particular explanation needed. Or you can ask for any specific hook explanation.

Comment: Hooks are to replace lifecycle functions because hooks don't work in class components and lifecycle functions don't exist in functional components. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) is the hooks documentation and if you are using class components and have not figured out why you shouldn't then read the hooks documentation again, especially [this part](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React classes you had lifecycle functions and state to do things but you didn't have them in functional components. The React defs came up with [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) where you can simplify your code and re use your code better by bundling up certain functionality in a custom hook. This was previously not possible with class components. Even with mix-ins like used in Vue they now have composition api that works similarly to hooks.

Let's say you want to have counter functionality that will log when a counter changes, have an up and down function and a counter value.

In a class you need to maintain this.state.counter that you change with this.up and this.down so you could implement this in a Counter class that extends React.Component or React.PureComponent and have a component that uses a counter extends Counter but then that component can still just have one counter. In hooks you can implement a counter with a custom hook and have multiple counters in one component.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useCallback,
  useRef,
  memo,
} = React;

//hooks, also custom hooks always start with "use"
const useCounter = (name, initialValue = 1) => {
  //local counter value and function to change it
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(initialValue);
  //ref created on mount with previous counter value
  const countRef = useRef(initialValue);
  //up and down functions created with useCallback so they
  //  will be created on mount and never change
  const up = useCallback(
    () => setCounter((c) => c + 1),
    []
  );
  const down = useCallback(
    () => setCounter((c) => c - 1),
    []
  );
  //effect that will log when counter changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (countRef.current !== counter) {
      console.log(`counter ${name} changed to`, counter);
      countRef.current = counter;
    }
  }, [counter, name]);
  //return up, down and counter
  return { up, down, counter };
};
//using memo makes UP2 a pure component so it'll not re
//  render since up is created with useCallback and is
//  not re created therefore the props passed to UP2 
//  don't change
const UP2 = memo(function UP2({ up, name }) {
  console.log(`UP2 for ${name} will only render once`);
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        //state updates are batched in synchronous
        //  event handlers so "chaged to" will log
        //  only once
        up();
        up();
      }}
    >
      +2
    </button>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  //first counter
  const {
    up: up1,
    down: down1,
    counter: counter1,
  } = useCounter('counter one');
  //second counter
  const {
    up: up2,
    down: down2,
    counter: counter2,
  } = useCounter('counter two', 2);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={up1}>UP</button>
        <button onClick={down1}>Down</button>
        <UP2 up={up1} name={'counter one'} />
        {counter1}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={up2}>UP</button>
        <button onClick={down2}>Down</button>
        <UP2 up={up2} name={'counter two'} />
        {counter2}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```